# RTL Support: Disabling it only for specific UI components

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, right-to-left

I have a custom video player Activity.

I am forced to enable RTL Support in my Application.

But doing so will result in a Right-To-Left aligned ProgressBar. (And that looks ugly)

**I want my ProgressBar to stay LTR in my RTL enabled Application.**

Is there any solution?

P.S. I am using Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Okay there is a simple solution for 4.2 and higher:

You can set the `android:layoutDirection` property in XML, it can have either rtl or ltr values.

The property overrides `android:supportsRtl` property in "application" segment of your manifest file.