# Prevent RTL in Android

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to force left to right layouts when the device language is any rtl language?
All XML Screens got broken when the language is changed to Arabic?

Comment: add supportRTL=false in menifest application tag

Comment: add `android:supportsRtl="false"` to your `application` in manifest

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963740/rtl-support-disabling-it-only-for-specific-ui-components) help?

Comment: Does this help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can forcefully disable rtl by changing its property `supportRtl="false"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.